# I am not able to use viewbinding in activity in Kotlin android ,where I have also used companion object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-viewbinding, companion-object

```
package com.example.birthdayapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.birthdayapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class birthdayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private  lateinit var binding: birthdayActivity


    //using companion object
    companion object {
       const  val NAME_EXTRA="Name_extra"
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //implementing view binding
        binding= birthdayActivity.inflate(layoutInflater) //here red line shows below inflate
        setContentView(binding.root)   //here red line shows below root


        //getting name from main activity
        val name=intent.getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA)

    }
}


//MainActivity

package com.example.birthdayapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.birthdayapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) //Here, I have successfully used viewbinding
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.birthdaybutn.setOnClickListener {
            val name=binding.nam.editableText.toString()
            val intent=Intent(this,birthdayActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(birthdayActivity.NAME_EXTRA,name)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

I have successfully used viewbinding in MainActivity but when I tried to use viewbindig in birthdayActivity , i got red lines for ( inflate and root keyword ) ,because i have used companion object in birthdayActiviy whereas I have not companion object in MainActiviy

Comment: Sometimes IDE fails to create `viewbinding` class, try rebuilding your project.

Comment: I have tried rebuilding my project but it still shows error

Comment: then make sure your `birthdayActivity` binding class name is correct, it's probably `BirthdayActivityBinding`.